# Check if the textbox contains Javascript code from Code Behind(C#) or Javascript itself

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, html, asp.net

I have a text box where it is fine to input html tags such as anchor, heading, etc. But the thing is I want to prevent user from entering Javascript code.
Currently I have a list of keyword that I detect and replace them.

```
var csv = "<script>,javascript,alert()";
        var csvSplit = csv.split(',');
        $("#txtValue").keyup(function() {
            var inputString = $("#txtValue").val();
            for (i = 0; i < csvSplit.length; i++) {
                if (inputString.indexOf(csvSplit[i]) > -1) {
                    var validString = inputString.replace(csvSplit[i], "");
                    $("#txtValue").val(validString);
                }
            }
        });
```

I don't think this is ideal solution.
Is there any other way in Javascript or C# ?

Can there be any way to execute string as javascript in background through c# and check how it acts ?

Comment: "But the thing is I want to prevent user from entering Javascript code" ..what does this means?? nakki kay karaychay ?

Comment: I want to stop user from submitting javascript code, through code behind C# or javascript itself. Can there be any way to execute string as javascript in background through c# and check how it acts ?

Comment: @Sagar Everyone speaks English here, please keep it that way.